# Поменять цвет элемента через метод программно WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

При нажатии на кнопку она должна поменять свой задний план. Когда я задавал новый цвет напрямую через класс  `Brushes`, то компиляция проходила корректно. Когда я поместил инструкции, задающие цвет аргумента в метод `ChangeButtonColors`, то компилятор выдавал ошибку:

```
error CS1503: Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать
из "System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush" в "System.Windows.Media.Brushes"
```

```cs
switch (rand.Next(0, 6))
{
    case 0:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Black);
        break;
    case 1:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.White, Brushes.Black);
        break;
    case 2:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Red);
        break;
    case 3:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Black);
        break;
    case 4:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Green);
        break;
    case 5:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Blue);
        break;
    case 6:
        ChangeButtonColors(Brushes.Magenta, Brushes.Black);
        break;
}
```

Сам метод:

```cs
private void ChangeButtonColors(Brushes background, Brushes foreground = Brushes.White)
{
    button.Foreground = foreground;
    button.Background = background; 
}
```

Все пространства имён подключены.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777233/

Comment: Такой вопрос не корректен для решения этой проблемы

Comment: Не очень понятно как у вас SolidColorBrush (кисть) должен конвертиться в Brushes, который просто класс со списком готовых кистей и сам кистью не является нигде. Ну и как у вас вообще компилится вот это `Brushes foreground = Brushes.White`

Comment: @vitdev НО когда я задавал напрямую цвета (```button.Foreground = Brushes.Black```), всё работало

Comment: Потому что свойство `Foreground` имеет тип `Brush`, который является базовым для `SolidColorBrush `. Конечно оно будет работать. А между `SolidColorBrush`, который в `Brushes.Black` и `Brushes` нет никакой связи.